# how to say 'is not in' in an active record query

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey I hope you can help me,

@courses = Course.where(:id != current_user.courses)

I want to get the courses, where the current user is not registered to

@courses = Course.where(:id => current_user.courses) gives me the courses where the user has registered to. But I want the opposite

Associations are just fine. I can use current_user.courses or current_user.assignments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

```
@courses = Course.where("id NOT IN (?)", current_user.courses)
```

The reason you can't use a pure array or hash condition is because you're negating ("NOT IN") the query. As far as I know, this can't be done without using the string based syntax. If you just wanted to find matching ("IN") items, you could use the hash form:

```
@courses = Course.where(:id => current_user.courses)
```

It's the negating ("NOT IN") part that makes it tricky.

More information can be found in the [Active Record Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions).

Comment: thank you mirthlab. Its working fine! what is "id not in (?)" ? Can I also use it with other queries?

Comment: I added a little more info and a link to the docs. Hope that helps. "NOT IN" just means "find stuff that's not in this list of ids" which is basically, _everything else_. There are a lot of neat tricks in the linked rails guides. Take a look :)

Comment: Oh I got a new problem now. I got 5 courses. I unregisted from all of them to test it. Now, because I use "@courses = Course.where("id NOT IN (?)", current_user.courses)" it is not displaying any courses in my index ^^

Comment: You probably just need to do a conditional check, if current_user.courses.nil? then just set @courses to Course.all, etc.

Comment: Using .empty? is probably more correct from a rails perspective. You can also do something like this: @courses = Course.where("id NOT IN (?)", current_user.courses) || Course.all

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to avoid using raw strings, you could use `ARel`

```
@courses = Course.where(Course.arel_table[:id].not_in(current_users.courses))
```

Unfortunately, `ARel` is not documented very well. I use [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/355-hacking-with-arel) as a reference.